# In C++ how do I split a string into multiple integers?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have a string of of five values, each separated by a space.

```
std::string s = "123 123 123 123 123";
```

How do I split these into an array of five integers?

Comment: read about strtol()   http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/

Comment: If you search for string splitting in C++, then converting strings to numbers in C++, you'll get your problem solved completely in about 5 minutes it takes to search.

Answer (score 9):

Use `std::stringstream` like so:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

...

std::stringstream in(s);
std::vector<int> a;
int temp;
while(in >> temp) {
  a.push_back(temp);
}
```

Comment: Or better yet, construct the `std::vector` like this `std::vector<int> v((std::istream_iterator<int>(iss)), std::istream_iterator<int>());` (need to `#include <iterator>`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you need a built in array, although it's usually better to use a `std::vector`, as suggested before, in the general case. I'm assuming you want to split the string at every space character.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string s = "123 123 123 123 123";
    std::istringstream iss(s);

    int arr[5];
    for (auto& i : arr) {
        iss >> i;
    }
}
```